# Change Assembler code to Delphi

Tags: assembly, delphi-xe

I need to compile an application that I have of 32Bist in 64Bist, but according to what I have read I can not have ASM code in 64Bist, that I must replace it with Pascal Puro.

You can help me with a guide for this, I have no knowledge in ASM!

```
 asm
   dw 310Fh // rdtsc
   mov TimerLo, eax
   mov TimerHi, edx
end;

Sleep(DelayTime);

asm
   dw 310Fh // rdtsc
   sub eax, TimerLo
   sbb edx, TimerHi
   mov TimerLo, eax
   mov TimerHi, edx
end;
```

Comment: Unless `rdtsc` is available as a function in Delphi, you won't be able to replace this code.

Comment: You can use asm in the Delphi 64 bit Windows compiler. Do you know what this code does? Delphi XE doesn't have a 32 bit compiler. It is often important to know what compiler you are using.

Comment: The code you posted does measure time from the CPU, without context where it is used and how, it's hard to say how to replace it correctly. If it is about delaying something, then just remove the artificial delays completely, slow SW is bad. (if the delays are waiting for something to happen, then wait until it happens, not fixed delay). If this is about some kind of performance profiling, then is it needed after the SW is already mature and not changing much? Unless it needs to measure time in runtime for the functionality itself.

Comment: BTW this thing is counting the CPU clock cycles that the sleep takes to execute. Is this some test to detect the CPU clock or something like that? Maybe it's some leftover that you can remove...

Comment: "*I can not have ASM code in 64Bist*" - that is not true. You can indeed use ASM code in 64bit in general. What you can't use is **inline** ASM inside a procedure/function that also has Pascal code in it. But you can write procedures/functions that are *entirely* ASM only. [This is covered in the Delphi documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Converting_32-bit_Delphi_Applications_to_64-bit_Windows#Inline_Assembly_code).

Comment: *"it is used to know the speed of the processor to provide this information to the user"* - sounds pretty useless to me, IMO you can just remove it. Judging by the bit you posted it is probably uselessly faulty too, not considering multi-core and multi-frequency possibilities (although I didn't check exact params of the `rdtsc`, maybe it's using some meaningful kind of timer, but I guess this is so legacy and oversimplified, that the result is not very meaningful). Rather use some OS call to get CPU info, in linux you can read virtual text file `/proc/cpuinfo` to get detailed CPU information.

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use asm on the Windows x64 Delphi compiler. For instance

```
function GetRDTSC: UInt64; 
asm
  RDTSC
  SHL   RDX, 32
  OR    RAX, RDX
end;
```

On x64 the `RDTSC` instruction clears the high 32 bits of the `RAX` and `RDX` registers which is what makes this code work.

Note that I am assuming that you use a sufficiently modern Delphi version that has support for the `RDTSC` instruction. Otherwise you can resort to `DW` as per the code in your question.  We don't know what version you are using because the question is mistagged.